# How can i merge two state into single state in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rxjs, frontend

I want to merge two state named Data and District value and create a single state named test.Since i am fetching two states value from different API.I cannot make a single state merging the data of the following states,i tried but when i tried to merge two state value a single states value i get but next state value cannot be obtained,since i tried to use spread operator but still cannot solve the issue.Following below are my code:Please help for solution:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
 import Axios from 'axios';

export default function Testmap() {
const [Data, setData] = useState([]);//fetched data
const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
const [District, setDistrict] = useState([]);
const [test, setTest] = useState({
    data: [],
    districts: []
});





useEffect(() => {
    //fetching data from api 
    Axios.get('https://covid19wst.yilab.org.np/api/v1/form')
        
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data)
            setTest({ ...test, data: res.data })
            setIsloading(false)

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    Axios.get('https://bipad.gov.np/api/v1/district/')
        .then(res => {
            setDistrict(res.data.results)
            setTest({ ...test, districts: res.data.results })



            setIsloading(false)

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

}, [])




console.log(isLoading);
console.log("data", Data);
console.log("districts>>", District);
console.log("test>>>", test);

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
)
  }
```

Following below is my output:
[image]

Here in above output i tried to keep two state values of data and districts in a single state test but when the code is run i cannot get update value with previous value when i used spread operator to preserve previous value.Still prevoius value is not preserved,how can i solve the issue?Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is a better option for handling multiple requests that do not depend on each other.

Consider having `loading` set to `false` only when both requests are finished.

Also, the state can be simplified like this:

```
export default function Testmap() {
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(false);
  const [test, setTest] = useState({
    data: [],
    districts: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsloading(true);

    Promise.all([
      Axios.get("https://covid19wst.yilab.org.np/api/v1/form"),
      Axios.get("https://bipad.gov.np/api/v1/district/"),
    ])
      .then((results) => {
        setIsloading(false);
        setTest({
          data: results[0].data,
          districts: results[1].data.results
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsloading(false);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it in 2 `useEffect` hooks:

1. the first one will run once and will fetch data into your `districts` and `data` states.
2. the second one will have `districts` and `data` in dependency array, so will run each time whenever `data` or `districts` changes.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function Testmap() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);//fetched data
    const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
    const [districts, setDistricts] = useState([]);
    const [test, setTest] = useState({
        data: [],
        districts: []
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        //fetching data from api
        Axios.get('https://covid19wst.yilab.org.np/api/v1/form')
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data);
                setIsloading(false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        Axios.get('https://bipad.gov.np/api/v1/district/')
            .then(res => {
                setDistricts(res.data.results);
                setIsloading(false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTest({...test, data, districts});
    }, [data, districts]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Axios documentation "Performing multiple concurrent requests"

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

Promise.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(function (results) {
    const acct = results[0];
    const perm = results[1];
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the both http request asycn so, then you can change the variable test state once, like this:

```
//fetching data from api 
const fetchDataFromApi = async () => {
    let dataResponse = []
    await Axios.get('https://covid19wst.yilab.org.np/api/v1/form')
        
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data)
            dataResponse = res.data
            setIsloading(false)

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    let districtResponse = []
    await Axios.get('https://bipad.gov.np/api/v1/district/')
        .then(res => {
            setDistrict(res.data.results)
            districtResponse = res.data.results
            setIsloading(false)

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

       setTest([...test, ...dataResponse, ...districtResponse])
    }
```